# Insert js in a Hugo post

Tags: html, d3.js, web, hugo

I am trying to use the Hugo engine to create a website from scratch. Prior to this I was using html pages. I was wondering if I have a post into.md how do I add the script inside this so that it could show me the output(eg a d3js visualization ) inside it.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include a specific script just for a specific page, you can define a [shortcode](https://gohugo.io/extras/shortcodes/), which takes the required input. Otherwise define it in the layout of your page, if it used on multiple pages.

Comment: Thank You @Pyth0n